# How can I create a gap in a CSS left border around an image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

Trying to figure out how to create a gap in a CSS left border around an image via CSS or JavaScript/jQuery.

I've found several answers how to do this with a gap on the top or bottom border, but couldn't figure out how to apply this to a left border.

[Here (https://ibb.co/cGS0vk)](https://ibb.co/cGS0vk) is an image of what I try to achieve.

Here is my HTML so far:

```
<div class="frame">
  <img class="quote" src="quote.jpg">
   <h2>Heading<h2>
   <p>Lorem ipsum<p>
</div>
```

And here is the CSS:

```
.frame {
    Border-top: 10px sloid grey;
    Border-right: 10px sloid grey;
    Border-bottom: 10px sloid grey;
}
.quotes {
    position: relative;
    right: 100px;
}
```

Comment: The image points to wrong link. Please fix it.

Comment: Invalid image link

Comment: You need to share the code you've tried so far

Comment: Sorry it's updated now

Comment: a screenshot will not help to help you, share your code and attemps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by using pseudo elements like `:before` and `:after`.

```css
.box {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  border: solid #000;
  border-width: 5px 5px 5px 0;
}

.box:before,
.box:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  background: #000;
  height: 30%;
  width: 5px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.box:after {
  top: auto;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Comment: Thank You @DanPhilip Exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @martinschwartz Could you be kind enough to accept the answer if it worked.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to SO and need 15 reputation in order to vote for an answer... So I'm unable to do this right now. However, I might check back after I get to 15 and vote for your answer.

Comment: ANSWER ACCEPTED!

Answer (score 0):

Best idea I can come up with using minimal amount of requirements:

Use the [::before/::after pseudo elements](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/a/after-and-before/) to place a background-color-matching element over top of an existing border. This essentially "slices" part of your border away.

HTML:

```
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrap { position: relative; width: 300px; height: 300px; background-color: #fff; }
.box { position: absolute; margin: auto; top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0; width: 200px; height: 200px; border: 10px solid #8af; }
.box::before { content: ''; position: absolute; width: 10px; height: 100px; margin: auto; left: -10px; top: 0; bottom: 0; background-color: #fff; }
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gam9s0mz/

*Edit* As noted, this method wouldn't work well with a background image. But only with solid background color matching.

Comment: It does not make the border tansparent, If you need to add a background image rather than a solid color. @martinschwartz

Comment: @DanPhilip That's right, thought I'll be able to just change the color to "transparent"

Comment: Better to use less markup's and more psuedo elements , because markups puts more load on the browser when scaling up.

Comment: @martinschwartz If you change the color to transparent the border beneath becomes visible.

Comment: You are correct, with the exception of border styles, such as rounded borders. Both methods have pros and cons, so go with what works for your implementation. I however don't see how this would scale worse since it's using less elements. The wrap div was just to show contrast in my example.